# Anchor link multiple telephone number

Tags: html

I have a telephone number in my web within an anchor like this:

`<a href="tel:+00-00-0000-0000">+00 00 0000 0000 / 0001</a>`

What I would want to get is something like `href="tel:+00-00-0000-0000 OR +00-00-0000-0001"`, so that when the user touches on the number inside the anchor he can chose to call one number or another. Is this posible?

For the record, I am using `<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">` to prevent default system stylings.

Thanks a lot

Comment: _"Is this posible?"_ With plain HTML, no. Possibly with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

make 2 hrefs

```
<div>
<a href="tel:+00-00-0000-0000">+00 00 0000 0000</a>/<a href="tel:+00-00-0000-0001"> 0001</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya, this is what I did. But I would want the user to be able to click the entire number and chose which one to call to

Comment: You want the user to click just to get to a selection menu? Use a modal window that gives the 2 options.  You can find css or JS modal solutions online.